# how to do display an information two day before today with java

Tags: java, date, datetime, datepicker

I want to develop a condition to display informations two day before the day specified, help me please if you have any idea

I used this solution but it give all date after today.

```
 Date dateEcheance=f.getDate_echeance();
 String fournisseur= f.getFournisseur().getNom();     
if ( System.currentTimeMillis()- dateEcheance.getTime() < 1728000000 ) 
             {
              msg = "La Facture du fournisseur: "+fournisseur+" prend fin le :"+dateEcheance;
              message.setMessage(msg);
              System.out.println("message: "+msg);
             }
```

Comment: For a time in the future, this will give you a negative number. A negative number is less than 1,728,000,000. Perhaps you should also check that the difference is greater than zero? Also, shouldn't that be just 172,800,000?

Comment: Yeah i know its not a good solution, for that i search an other proposition to get informations 2 day before today !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
        long inputTime = getUserInput();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(inputTime);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -2);

        if(yourCondition.getTimeInMillis() < cal.getTimeInMillis()) {
            //You have a hit, do something
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by getUserInput()?

Comment: "two day before the day specified" -  the specified day

Comment: and what about : yourCondition.getTimeInMillis(), i understand that my condition is " dateEcheance" the type of my condition is Date and i can not to cast dateEcheance to calendar

Comment: It is a long value. Time can be represented as a long in java. This is the same in calendar and in Date too. You can create both with a long value and get the time in milliseconds from both too. So you can use dateEcheance.getTime() in exchenge. :) Check this page. Here are some examples: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Adds or subtracts the specified amount of time to the given calendar field, based on the calendar's rules.

```
public static void subtractDays(Date d, int days)
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(d);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, -days);
        d.setTime( c.getTime().getTime() );
    }
```